# why app is not run in android device version 2.3 to 2.3.7

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
   >
```

My minsdkversion & target is above But this app is not run in 2.3 android device version.So plz help me

Comment: What you mean for "is not run in android"? Can't install? Crashes?

Comment: App Install but when open it is crashes nd forced close..

Comment: Show us the logcat. You should always do that when something is crashing. My guess is: it's probably a holo theme you're using that's not present below 3.0 (I'm guessing that because you've tagged your question android-holo-everywhere). In any case, logcat will tell you the real cause even if it's not that.

Comment: Yes, Android 2.3 doesn't have getActionBar unless you use ActionBarSherlock, or use one of the compatibility libraries. Next time, you can post your logcat directly into your question by editing it. Comments are not made for that purpose.

Comment: Now I what to do.because i already upload this app on lay store

Comment: @Rajesh - please don't paste code into comments. Its nearly impossible to read and it belongs with the question. Instead: (1) add the logcat output to your question by clicking the *Edit* button; and (2) delete the comments with the logcat output.

Comment: My App Already complete.Now My minsdkversion is 8 & Targetsdkversion is 19.Now i want  to do My minsdkversion 11.how it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: in this code how can i use getsupportActionbar();

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: ya i used ur suggestion bt when getSupportActionBar() write it .it give error

Comment: If you don't give me more information I can't help you. "It give error" doesn't help.

Comment: My App Already complete.Now My minsdkversion is 8 & Targetsdkversion is 19.Now i want  to do My minsdkversion 11.how it possible?